# .htaccess in public_html blocks Wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess in the public_html folder with the following content:

```
RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex index3.php

RewriteRule    ^faq/?$    faq.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^privacy/?$    privacy.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^blog/?$    blog.php    [NC,L]
```

The following line blocks the wordpress blog installed in my site:

```
DirectoryIndex index3.php
```

I mean, whenever I go to http://mywebsite.net/blog/wp-admin/, I receive this error:

> You don't have permission to access /blog/wp-admin/ on this server.

There is another .htaccess file at /public_html/blog/.htaccess with this content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

How can I fix this? What's strange is I don't remember modifying anything, this has just happened all of a sudden.

Folder structure

```
public_html
   index.php
   index3.php
   faq.php
   privacy.php
   blog
     wp-admin
     wp-content
     wp-includes
     .htacces
     index.php
```

Comment: Delete the blog rule in your first .htaccess file...

Comment: That doesn't help. Removing the `DirectoryIndex index3.php` line helps but that is obviously out of the question.

Comment: Changing it to `DirectoryIndex index.php` did the trick, but I have no idea why? It's a strange world.

Answer (score -1):

If your Wordpress site is installed at `user/public_html/blog/` then you wouldn't want to rewrite this to `blog.php`. This would prevent you from being able to go to `/blog/wp-admin.php`.

```
RewriteRule    ^blog/?$    blog.php    [NC,L]
```

If I am understanding this correctly, this line may be your problem. Please state more of what you are trying to accomplish with the .htaccess file as well.

Comment: That line should have been commented out, I am sorry. There is no blog.php as I am running a wordpress blog under mywebsite.com/blog. So this is not the solution